# Meteor 0.7 error

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteorite

I need help.

After upgrading meteor to 0.7 version, application can not start with strange error (but, before update and if i create a new app - it worked well):

```
ant@ant-VirtualBox:~/testtracker$ mrt

Stand back while Meteorite does its thing

Done installing smart packages

Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!

[[[[[ ~/testtracker ]]]]]


/home/ant/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
    at parseStack (/home/ant/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/tools/buildmessage.js:257:26)
    at Object.exception (/home/ant/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/tools/buildmessage.js:399:17)
    at /home/ant/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/tools/packages.js:448:22
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/ant/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at _.extend.build (/home/ant/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/tools/packages.js:235:7)
    at /home/ant/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/tools/packages.js:1041:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/ant/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at _.extend.build (/home/ant/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/tools/packages.js:1040:7)
    at _.extend.getForApp (/home/ant/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/tools/library.js:285:9)
    at /home/ant/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/tools/bundler.js:1646:25
    at Object.capture (/home/ant/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/tools/buildmessage.js:175:5)
    at Object.exports.bundle (/home/ant/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/tools/bundler.js:1580:31)
    at /home/ant/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/tools/run.js:532:32
    at /home/ant/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/tools/fiber-helpers.js:24:12
```

Please, give me advice, what i can do with this.

Comment: What version of Node do you have? (`node -v`) I think it should be v0.10.22.

Comment: version 0.10.23 installed

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update mrt packages as well.

```
mrt update
```

Comment: `mrt` by default will update all meteorite packages.

Comment: i did it, but result the same. Also, i reinstalled meteor and meteorite and it gave nothing

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the mongodb instance from meteor or do you use an external mongodb instance (used by MONGO_URL env) ?

I got the same problem because it seems that mongolab doesn't accept the new oplog system from  meteor.

Finally i now use the internal mongodb instance because i didn't find another solution from mongolab.